# How to secure liquibase properties (database password etc.) in springboot application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, liquibase

While developing a springboot-liquibase application following [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-liquibase) I need to specify the database username + password as liquibase.user and liquibase.password in the application.properties file. I am looking for a better secure way to use these parameter (dynamically fetched from some other place and use inside my java code)
Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of things you can do:

1. You can encrypt you properties file using [jasypt-spring-boot](https://github.com/ulisesbocchio/jasypt-spring-boot). For more details have a look at [demo app](https://github.com/ulisesbocchio/jasypt-spring-boot/tree/master/jasypt-spring-boot-demo)
2. If you are developing distributed system, then [spring-cloud-config](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-confighttp://)  provides server and client-side support for externalized configuration in a distributed system. With the Config Server you have a central place to manage external properties for applications across all environments

Answer (score 1):

### [Spring Cloud Config](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/)

This project allows you to use an external, centralized configuration repository for one or more applications.  You don't need to rebuild your application if a property changes.  You can simply change the property in your configuration repository and even push the changes to all of your applications.

See this [Getting Started Guide.](http://spring.io/guides/gs/centralized-configuration/)